# How to get CSS font-weight to display?

Tags: css

I am having an issue with the CSS `font-weight` property. I have set the `font-weight` to 100, and yet I see no difference from when it was at 600. This has been noticed across multiple websites. It has been observed in Chrome, Chromium, and Firefox on Ubuntu.

I am using Helvetica for the font. I need to make the font lighter.

Is there a work-around for this?

Thanks.

Comment: Does the font have a weight built into it? Otherwise, 400 is normal, 700 is bold.

Comment: The font is just standard Helvetica, @Chad. So, I believe, no.

Comment: So probably not then-- if you want to load a lighter font, you typically have to upload that font as well.

Comment: You haven't given enough information (and font-weight isn't a selector).

Comment: Seems to work fine in Chrome/Win7: http://jsfiddle.net/isherwood/PC8b4/

Comment: @isherwood, does not work on my machine. Maybe this is just an Ubuntu bug?

Comment: Like Jason said below, those particular weights may not be available. Can't you do 'normal' and 'bold' for better compatibility?

Comment: The font has to support those font-weights else it will default to normal or bold. Some useful info at: http://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/f/font-weight/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot make a font lighter unless the font has lighter typeface. Helvetica does not. (Neither does Arial, which is what Helvetica is actually mapped to in most computers, namely on Windows systems that lack Helvetica.) Most fonts commonly used on web pages do not.

The `font-weight` declaration, at least with values less than 400, does *not* modify anything in fonts. It does not make strokes thinner. Instead, it *selects* a lighter (or bolder, depending on the value) typeface from a font family *when available*, i.e. when the font designer has crafted it.

In [Google Fonts](http://www.google.com/fonts), there are some nice sans-serif fonts with lighter typefaces, such as Roboto, Open Sans, and Source Sans Pro. Note that 100 is the smallest value of `font-weight, and very few fonts have typefaces that light; normally 300, or sometimes 200, is what you should look for.

Answer (score 1):

Not all fonts have all Font Weights inside of them ([MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/font-weight)).

> **100, 200, 300, 400, 500, 600, 700, 800, 900**
>
> Numeric font weights for fonts that provide more than just normal and bold. If the exact weight given is unavailable, then 600-900 use the closest available darker weight (or, if there is none, the closest available lighter weight), and 100-500 use the closest available lighter weight (or, if there is none, the closest available darker weight). This means that for fonts that provide only normal and bold, 100-500 are normal, and 600-900 are bold.